# Python runs file from specific folder but can't run from others

Tags: python, vbscript, 32bit-64bit

I have a VB script which I want to run with python27, when I place my VBS in desktop it can be run successfully but when I copy the same file to another folder and want to run from there it doesn't run!! this is running me crazy, I can't understand the logic, can someone please help me?!

I have python 32bit installed on my 64bit win 7 because I need some python modules that are only available for 32bit version, also my VBS is based on 32bit DLL.

Runs correctly:

```
import os
os.system("C:\Users\OFFICE2\Desktop\TSATResultSaver.vbs")
```

Doesn't run:

```
import os
os.system("C:\My Modules\TSATResultSaver.vbs")
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the space in the path?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't run".  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure permissions on those two folders are the same. Also, I would try a folder without a space in the path (there are no spaces in the first path, but "My Modules" contains a space.

Comment: @moba You can thank him by selecting his answer. It gives him more points.